# getting material-angular container to take up the rest of the container

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Sorry if this is a n00b question but I'm trying to build a chrome app that's using angular-material for the ui.  I basically have the following.  I'm not listing the exact code, just the idea...

```
<section layout-fill>
    <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
    <md-tabs></md-tabs>
    <md-content>
       <form></form>
    </md-content>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-content flex></md-content>
</section>
```

I don't want the last `<md-content>` to fill the remaining space at the bottom of the container and then scroll for the overflow.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I should have really given this a little more time.  `style="height: 100%"` on the parent section solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the parent to have 100% height if you give add the property `layout="column"`, this way you don't need to add custom styles. Can you try and let me know if it worked? Cheers